# Chrome devtools doesn't show all console errors

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have multiple Google accounts, and I have multiple Chrome windows open where I am logged in with different accounts.

Under a first account, I see the following CSP errors in Chrome devtools:

[image]

But under a second Google account, I don't see any errors in Chrome devtools for the same web page:

[image]

Here is what I've tried:

- Empty cache and hard reload
- Under devtools, I went to Settings, clicked "Restore defaults and reload", and restarted Chrome
- Went to chrome://flags/, clicked "Reset all", and restarted Chrome

But I still don't see the CSP errors.  Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe the site serves different content (and even CSP) randomly as a part of A/B testing? Compare the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

Under the settings cog for the console, there is an option "Show CORS errors in console".  You probably have that checked in one set of DevTools and not in the other
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure you can log in with separate accounts just between browsers, unless one has incognito mode - because if they are on the same site, they'd share the same cookies. If you log into your webmail, you can load a new window and access the same account without having to log back in again. 
Can you confirm it is in icognito mode and that you have a new dev console per window?